# How do I use Type.forName to deserialize a generic list of SObjects?

Tags: apex, json, generics

When the new Apex type methods were added in Summer '12, it was possible to do

```
Type t = Type.forName('MyClass');
MyClass newObj = (MyClass)t.newInstance();
```

What is the equivalent when I want to instantiate a List of such a class for which I only know the name at runtime?

I am also trying to create multiple records using `JSON.deserialize`. I think the answer to the earlier question may also help me with creating a List of such objects with `JSON.deserialize(jsonStringOfSeveralObjects, appropriateListClass)`.

Note: I am able to use a Type method to create a record of a custom object like this:

```
Type oType = Type.forName(‘MySobjectName’);                                           
sObject rec = (sObject) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, oType);
```

But when the JSON string is an array of objects I am unable to use a method similar to the example shown below:

```
List<InvoiceStatement> deserializedInvoices = 
    (List<InvoiceStatement>)JSON.deserialize(JSONString, List<InvoiceStatement>.class);
```

Can you suggest the right format to use with `List<>` to create multiple records? I am specifically looking for corresponding substitutes for `List<InvoiceStatement>` and `List<InvoiceStatement>.class` that can be dynamically determined.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is to deserialize into a `List<SObject>`. This works for me:

```
String jsonString = '[{"Name":"A1"},{"Name":"A2"}]';
Type t = Type.forName('List<Account>');
List<SObject> lo = (List<SObject>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, t);
for (SObject o : lo) {
    System.debug(o.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() + ', Name: ' + o.get('Name'));
}
```

Output:

```
Account, Name: A1
Account, Name: A2
```

Comment: Got this question by email - it was too good not to post!

Comment: You can serialize into a subtyped list, as well. I tested this using: `Type t = Type.forName('List<Account>');
Account[] x = (Account[])JSON.deserialize('[{"Name":"Test"},{"Name":"Test 2"}]', t);`

Comment: Does that work for non-standard objects?

Comment: I just found out that in case where you have `List <WrapperClass>` - Type.forName('List<WrapperClas>') returns null. Instead you must use Type t = List<WrapperClass>.class and make sure you don't add a whitespace between List and < because it'll fail. I find that weird.

Comment: Apex classes work differently from sobjects? That is weird. I'll alert the authorities...

Comment: @e-bacho 2.0, I am not seeing the same issue you are seeing.  I do notice a typo (missing the last "s" on Type.forName('List<WrapperClas>')), but that may be a typo here rather than copy paste of a typo in your code.  Could you provide more detail?  
  
`Type t = Type.forName('List<ICheck>');  
system.debug(t);  
  
11:17:11:059 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|LIST<ICheck>`

Comment: Thanks @metadaddy! @Josh, when you have inner class in your code and a list of objects from that class, it seems like you cannot get the type if you use the `forName` method - e.g. `Type t = Type.forName('List<YourInnerClass>')` will not work. It only works when you use the Type property `class` but you need to make sure you don't add whitespace character - `Type t = List <YourInnerClass>.class` will not work (note the space between `List` and `<YourInnerClass>`. Instead the only way it works is using the .class property without a whitespace character - `Type t = List<YourInnerClass>.class`

Comment: @BorisBachovski- thanks for the tip; one thing I have noticed is that `Type.forName(someClassName)` does not work if `someClassName` is a private inner class (V36), works for public inner classes - posting in case someone else sees this in the future